# My database design for movie database

Tags: sql, database

If it best way to Normalize???

```
1:Actors:-
Id
Name
Sex
DOB
BIO

2:Movies:-
Id
Name
Year of release
Plot
Poster
Foreign Key(ProducerId)

3:Producers:-
Id
Name
Sex
DOB
Bio

4:-MovieActorsMap
Primary Key(Foreign Key(ActorId)
Foreign Key(MovieId))
```

**RelationShips:-**

- Actor can act in multiple movies
- Movie can have multiple actors
- Movie has only one producer
- Producer can produce multiple movies

I am right to create databse table???

Comment: Seems ok for a start, but what about directors and other cast members that are not actors? I would also change `sex` to the `gender`.

Comment: What if an actor can be a producer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i chage table 4 table to 2 table and i set this to UI side...Thank you for your help on this much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create actors and ditectors in the entitytype table.
eg. type1 director
    type2 actor
that way it will be easy to add more members(entity) in future

```
   1:Persons:-
    Id
    EntityTypeId
    Name
    Gender
    DOB
    BIO

    2:Movies:-
    Id
    Name
    Year of release
    Plot
    Poster
    Foreign Key(ProducerId)

    3:EntityType:-
    EntityTypeId
    Entity

    4:-MovieActorsMap
    Primary Key(Foreign Key(ActorId)
    Foreign Key(MovieId))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this much appreciated :)

Comment: What is `EntityType` again and why would that be necessary (*can you see any possible problems with this*) ?

Comment: EntityType table will help you to differentiate your members (persons). eg entitypeid  1 = actor, entitytypeid 2 = director, entitytypeid 3 = producer and so on.

Comment: Lets use Mel Gibson and the movie Braveheart and Apocalypto as examples. He was in actor in the first and produced the later. What would his entity type be.

Comment: he will be in both entity 1 and 2.

Comment: My point is that this depends on the move and its not necessary to capture it with the person at all. The OP did not capture it either as a user property. What you have without it should be sufficient, you can see the producer and you can see the actors.

Comment: you might need MoviesId on the persons table to link members to the movies table

Answer (score 1):

Producers and Actors have identical fields so you could move them in one table Persons and add a forign key id_type to differentiate between various types of people that can be in a movie. Of course youll need to add one more table Type with two fields id and title

Comment: Thank you for your help on this much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

4:-MovieActorsMap
Primary Key(Id) auto increment
Foreign Key(ActorId)
Foreign Key(MovieId)

An actor can make several movies, if you put him as a primary key, he can only make one movie.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this much appreciated :)